# Suddenly unable to create socket

Tags: android, python, sockets

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 12345          # Reserve a port for your service.
s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port
s.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection.
print "entered loop"
c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
```

I was using this piece of code to simply create a socket and accept a connection on it from an Android. Simple enough.
But since the past few hours (with no changes to the code), python is for some reason unable to create the socket. I don't get any errors, but it's forever stuck at the `s.accept()` line.

I tried using `Fing`, a network diagnostics app on my Android to see the open ports, and indeed, Python is unable to create/open the socket. Earlier, as soon as I ran the code and rescanned on Fing, I was able to see the port open and test a TCP connection on it.

Sometimes, randomly in between, it works for one or two attempts.

What could be going wrong? I've tried to change port. I don't know what to debug since there isn't any error!

Answer (score 0):

Same Error occur to me . it was due to not closing the Socket . Try Closing the Sockets.
Else it will work for once when ever you will run and then after that it will start causing problems.